# I want to change UTC time zone to Pakistan time zone in Django 4.1.2

Tags: django, django-timezone

This is my code below and it is not working

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Pakistan'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

it is giving me this error

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

Comment: Did you contact the administrator?

Comment: Seems like you need to set ***`Asia/Karachi`*** instead of `Asia/Pakistan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to add `Country Name`.

Instead of this:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Pakistan'
```

Try this:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Add here city name with first letter capital'
```

For example:

Here in india, we need to add city name.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata' #Added a city name here for india
```

Answer (score 2):

The default time zone for Pakistan is calculated on `Karachi`, so instead of `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Pakistan'`:

```
TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Karachi"
```

List of [standard Timezone list](https://gist.github.com/arpit/1035596)